# How to fill svg with a random color?

Tags: css, svg, random

I am using this code but I'd like my fill and stroke color lo be selected randomly from an array.
This is my css:

```
 <style>          
      #svg.clickit .logo {
          fill: #002100;
          stroke: #002100;
          transition: 1s;
      }
  </style>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use jQuery, ie:

```
var random = Math.floor(Math.random()*array.length)

$('#svg.clickit .logo ').css({ fill: array[random], stroke: array[random] })
```